# the sqlparametercollection only accepts non-null sqlparameter type objects not byte[] objects

Tags: c#

I have the following code that throws an exception when run:

> the sqlparametercollection only accepts non-null sqlparameter type objects not byte[] objects

I don't understand where this error occurs exactly within this method:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // error handling removed

        cc.cn = new SqlConnection(cs.DBconn);
        cc.cn.Open();
        string cb = "insert into UserRegistration(U_ID,UserId,Name,Address,City,ContactNo,Email,Photo) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8)";
        cc.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
        cc.cmd.Connection = cc.cn;
        cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", txtId.Text);
        cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", txtUserId.Text);
        cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", txtUserName.Text);
        cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", txtAddress.Text);
        cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", txtCity.Text);
        cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6", txtContactNo.Text);
        cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", txtEmailId);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(Picture.Image);
        bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@d8", SqlDbType.Image);
        p.Value = data;
        cc.cmd.Parameters.Add(p.Value);
        cc.cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cc.cn.Close();
        st1 = lblId.Text;
        st2 = "added the new User'" + txtUserName.Text + "' having User id '" +txtUserId.Text + "'";
        cf.LogFunc(st1, System.DateTime.Now, st2);
        btnSave.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

What should I change to not get that error?

Comment: Please provide more information - and cut your code down to *just* what is needed to demonstrate the problem. Currently the body of your question has no text whatsoever explaining the issue, we don't know where the error occurs, and there's an inappropriate amount of code. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: _Wall of code sans-description, critical hits you for `10 damage`!_

Comment: I was expecting "cc.cmd.Parameters.Add("@d8",p.Value)" instead of "cc.cmd.Parameters.Add(p.Value)" . are they same?

Comment: i am saving users data in to database including users photo.i fill all info and when i click on save button it gives runtime exception..

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems in that code blob:

```
 cc.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", txtEmailId.Text); // use the Text property!

 SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@d8", SqlDbType.Image);
 p.Value = data;
 cc.cmd.Parameters.Add(p); // add the SqlParameter instance, not the byte[] array
```

and not strictly needed but as you don't run a select statement you better call [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`

```
 int rowsChanged = cc.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With these changes you should be good to go for these errors.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteReader()` is only for `SELECT` queries. you need to use `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: Not necessarily. The command text is executed which can contain any valid tsql batch of statements. In this particular case the ExecuteReader is not needed because there is no select statement at the end, so no records will be returned.

Comment: @rene it will not cause any problem but will not return since there is no select statement.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand *will not return*. Are you saying that ExecuteReader will hang for ever in this case?

Comment: "not return rows". sorry, I missed to add "rows"